# Deadlock in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two stored procedures, both insert rows into the same table.

Once stored procedure call regular time interval and another stored procedure call by user event. Sometimes both stored procedure are called together and at this time deadlock occurs.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. Retry the query that was chosen as the victim.

Comment: Please. Show your stored proc code and structure of tables involved

Answer (score 0):

Lock at the beginning of the SP and unlock at the end.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187749.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx

Comment: Don't recommend something that will be removed in future versions.

Comment: @Oded : just follow the link in it to get it for future versions.

Comment: Then why not post that link in the first place?

Comment: Both of those links give information about finding out what locks are currently in place, rather than (as I'd guessed when I read this answer) about taking an explicit lock

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the table at the beginning of your both sprocs. This way there will be no deadlocks because data modification will have to wait until the other sproc finishes. See the following command:

```
select 1 from theTable with (tablock, holdlock) where 1=0;
```

It also needs to be done inside a transaction. The table will be editable when the transaction finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider detecting the condition and retrying.  Have each procedure back off for a short random amount of time